# Three.jsでのTGA読み込みについて

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.jsでTGA読み込みを行うためにTGALoaderをインクルードし,

```
//該当部のみ抜粋
var loader;
var tgaLoader = new THREE.TGALoader( this.manager );
loader = tgaLoader;
var materialLoader = new THREE.MaterialLoader( this.manager );
var texture = loader.load( fullPath, function ( t ) {

            t.flipY = false;
            t.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            t.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

            if ( isSphericalReflectionMapping === true ) {

                t.mapping = THREE.SphericalReflectionMapping;

            }

} );
```

としましたが、

> WebGL: drawArrays: texture bound to texture unit 1 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'. Or the texture is Float or Half Float type with linear filtering while OES_float_linear or OES_half_float_linear extension is not enabled.

というエラーによって表示されませんでした。TGALoaderをDefaultLoaderに変え、リソースも変更すると正しく読み込まれることは確認しています。
Three.jsのサンプルサイト（http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_tga.html）でも私の環境では同様のエラーでTGAファイルが読み込まれません。

Answer (score 2):

Three.js r74で直ってます。

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_tga.html

Comment: エラーも吐かず正しく実行できました。ありがとうございます。